# Combining data in a specific format

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I am struggling with processing my data, I need to combine data to use for look up later on.

Example dataframe:

```
             rtu         rail       module
0            213            3           29
1            217            2           28
2            223            2           26
3            224            3           26
4            229            4           29
5            225            3           27
6            222            3           28
7            226            3           29
```

I would like to combine these 3 columns in the format `rtu:rail(module)` example:

```
213:003(029)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert values to strings and join with [`Series.str.zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html):

```
df['new'] = (df['rtu'].astype(str) + ':' + 
             df['rail'].astype(str).str.zfill(3) + '(' + 
             df['module'].astype(str).str.zfill(3) + ')')
print (df)
   rtu  rail  module           new
0  213     3      29  213:003(029)
1  217     2      28  217:002(028)
2  223     2      26  223:002(026)
3  224     3      26  224:003(026)
4  229     4      29  229:004(029)
5  225     3      27  225:003(027)
6  222     3      28  222:003(028)
7  226     3      29  226:003(029)
```

Solution with `f-string`s:

```
df['new'] = df.apply(lambda x: f"{x['rtu']}:{str(x['rail']).zfill(3)}({str(x['module']).zfill(3)})", axis=1)
```

And without `f-string`s:

```
df['new'] = df.apply(lambda x: str(x['rtu']) + ':' + str(x['rail']).zfill(3) + '(' + str(x['module']).zfill(3) + ')', axis=1)
```